# Deactivate buttons when semantic zoom changes

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to deactivate some buttons when `ZoomOutView` is active. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709928.aspx) the name of the VisualStateGroup is "SemanticZoomStates" and the name of the VisualState is "ZoomOutView". So I tried the following:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SemanticZoomStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="ZoomInView" />

        <VisualState x:Name="ZoomOutView">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="editDocButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="deleteDocButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

When I put the `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`-elements into let's say the "Snapped" VisualState (and the appropriate VisualStateGroup) it works, so there shouldn't be a problem with the button names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have changed `IsEnabled` to `(UIElement.IsEnabled)`

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SemanticZoomStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="ZoomInView" />
        <VisualState x:Name="ZoomOutView">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="editDocButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="deleteDocButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: Thanks, but nope, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: `editDocButton` and `deleteDocButton` is a part of `SemanticZoom` ?

Comment: No, it's part of the `Page.BottomAppBar`. Is that a problem? But why does it work if I put the `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` inside the snapped visual state?

Comment: I am not sure, but I doubt as `VisualStateGroup x:Name="SemanticZoomStates"` have only semantic zoom scope while snapped visual state has page level scope. I recommend you to use `ViewChangeCompleted` event. In that you can use property `e.IsSourceZoomedInView`